# ANativeWindow_getHeight subtracts nav bar height sometimes

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a C++ app that runs as the home app. I am testing on Android 5.0.2.

When I restart my app ANativeWindow_getHeight returns to me a height of 752. This is the screen height minus the nav bar at the bottom. This is the result even though the nav bar is not showing and the area of the window is indeed 800 pixels.

When I reboot the device and it launches my home app immediately, ANativeWindow_getHeight returns the actual window height of 800.

Is there anyway I can reliably get the actual window height in all scenarios?